# How to chdir to symlink source and not target in .screenrc

Tags: directory, symlink, gnu-screen

Is there a way to tell `screen` not to dereference symlinks when one is passed to the `chdir` command?

In my `.screenrc` I have commands like this:

```
chdir /data/project1
screen -t "project1"
chdir /data/project2
screen -t "project2"
```

The idea being that when I launch `screen`, I get a few terminals preloaded in a bunch of common directories I use frequently.

Unfortunately everything in `/data` is a symlink on my system, so when I load `screen` with the above commands, the terminals are left in different directories, like `/mnt/remote/server1/long/path/to/project1` instead of `/data/project1`.  I have to type `cd /data/project1` in the terminal to get into the folder I want.

Since the paths I'm using are very long and can change, I prefer getting in the habit of using my `/data` shortcuts so that I don't have to change any habits if I relocate the files elsewhere.

Is there some way to tell `screen` that, when using `chdir` and the target is a symlink, not to dereference the symlink and to just change into that directory anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just misunderstand what happens there.

When you are in

```
/mnt/remote/server1/long/path/to/project1
```

with your shell and type

```
cd /data/project1
```

then you do not change the directory. You just change what the shell is showing. The shell tells logical and physical directory hierarchies apart. `screen` (and more or less everything else) does not.

The easiest solution is probably to add some code to `.bashrc` (assuming you use `bash`):

```
test "$PWD" = '/mnt/remote/server1/long/path/to/project1' && cd /data/project1
```

Comment: Interesting, you are right.  Running `/usr/bin/pwd` from `/data/project1` does indeed print `/mnt/remote/server1...`.  I was assuming the symlinks were resolved at a much lower level than they actually are!

Comment: @Malvineous Symlinks can easily be detected but the default is to just not care about them. There are a few exceptions: shells, `find`, `ls`, backup / copy software.

Comment: Right!  Well, after considering piping commands to bash from my `.screenrc` and bind mounts, I ended up settling on your solution as the cleanest.  I used ``[[ "$PWD" == "$1"* ]] && cd `pwd | sed "s|$1|$2|"` `` in a function so that I could handle a whole bunch of folders in the same prefix.  Thanks!

Comment: @Malvineous You do not even need `sed`: `cd "${PWD/"$1"/"$2"}"`